# wx: Why can't a wxstaticbox be used as a window parent?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm building a UI using wxFormBuilder and generating code for python from it.

I've been trying to place wx*sizers (wxBoxSizer, wxGridSizer, wxFlexGridSizer, wxGridBagSizer) inside of wxStaticBoxSizers. I think it looks nice as a UI element to have that little label in the top left-hand corner, and wxStaticBoxSizers have this. When I'm editing my layout in the wxFormBuilder program, I don't get any errors or anything that would make me think that doing this would be a problem.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So the wxStaticBoxSizer is the **parent** of the wxFlexGridSizer. As you can see, the editor shows this relationship properly, but when I run my python code, I get this debug alert:

```
..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(242): assert "!parent ||
!exDynamicCast(parent, wxStaticBox)" failed in
wxWindowBase::CreateBase(): wxStaticBox can't be used as a window
parent!

Call stack:
[00] wxAppConsole::wxAppConsole
```

and if I continue to run the program, none of the children will show up properly inside of the wxStaticBoxSizer.

Does anyone know about this error? Or about a way to achieve what I have in a different way that won't cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

wxPython 2.8 not support wxstaticbox used as a window parent.
please upgrade to wxPython 4.0.3 will fix the problem.